# Getting error in jmeter beanshell response while code is working fine in eclipse

Tags: jmeter

I have created a java program to count occurrences from a csv file and working fine in eclipse. Below is the code.

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class ReadExcelDemo {
    public ReadExcelDemo(FileWriter fileWriter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    static void countEachWords(String fileName, Map < String, Integer > words) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    
    while (file.hasNext())
    {
        //String[] w=file.split(" ");
        String word=file.next();
        String key = word.split(",")[1];
        Integer count = words.get(key);
        if(count !=null)
            count++;
        else
            count =1;
        words.put(key, count);
    }
    file.close();
}
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Map<String, Integer> words= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        
        countEachWords("C:\\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\\Results\\Login.csv", words);
        FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\\Results\\output.csv");
        
        for(String keyset : words.keySet()) {
            
            String data = keyset +","+ words.get(keyset);
            String data1 = keyset;
            Integer data2= words.get(keyset);
            
            csvWriter.append(data);
            csvWriter.append("\n");         
        }
        csvWriter.close();
    }
}
```

While running in jmeter beanshell throwing below error.

```
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import java.io.FileNotFoundException; import java.io.FileWr . . . '' Encountered "<" at line 16, column 57.
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this.[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Map<String, Integer>` is the problematic statement, Beanshell lis not Java and it doesn't support modern Java features including [diamond operator](https://medium.com/@aayushid159/diamond-operator-in-java-aad0f8c2726e)

If you want to proceed with Beanshell you need to remove these type declarations and leave just raw types like:

```
Map words= new HashMap();
```

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting as:

- Groovy supports all modern Java features
- Groovy adds more ["syntax sugar" on top of them](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/)
- [Groovy performs much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for help. Incorporated your suggestion. Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Written code in JSR223 Sampler. Below is the code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;    
import java.io.FileWriter;    
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.PrintStream;    
import java.util.HashMap;    
import java.util.Map;    
import java.util.Scanner;

System.out.println("Program started");

static void countEachWords(String fileName, Map words) throws FileNotFoundException

{

Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
while (file.hasNext())   
{   
//String[] w=file.split(" ");    
String word=file.next();
String key = word.split(",")[0];
Integer count = (Integer) words.get(key);
if(count !=null)
count++;
else
count =1;
words.put(key, count);
}
file.close();
}
System.out.println("Starting main method");
Map words= new HashMap();
countEachWords("${inputRawFileToCountOccurrences}", words);
FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter("${inputFileForDBUpdate}");

for(Object keyset : words.keySet()) {
//String key = keyset.split(",")[1];
String data = keyset +","+ words.get(keyset);  
//String data1 = keyset; 
Integer data2= (Integer) words.get(keyset);    
csvWriter.flush();    
System.out.println(data);    
System.out.println(data2);   
csvWriter.append(data);   
csvWriter.append("\n");    
}   
csvWriter.close();
```